# htaccess redirect working for postman not for chrome (CORS)

Tags: java, .htaccess, rest, cors

I have a web service running in AWS (DomainA) and it is runnning fine. It is a REST service made in Java using JAX-WS and Jersey. I have a responsefilter on which adds access to all domains (Access-control-allow-origin *) and this should be working because if I remove it, I can not even get the web service to work locally.

I have bought a domain on one.com (DomainB) in which I redirect all requests to DomainA using .htaccess. Now, when I try to call some REST method on DomainB this works fine wherever I call it (if it is a GET method). If it is a POST method it also works for POSTMAN but in Chrome I get the infamous:

```
Failed to load "ServiceB". Redirect from "ServiceB" to "ServiceA" has "MyPage" been blocked by CORS policy: No Access-Control-Allow-Origin is present...
```

If I call DomainA directly I can see in my response headers that all domains are allowed and everything works fine.

Any ideas why CORS is not working when it is through my DomainB?

Answer (score 0):

It's Chrome itself which 'enforces' CORS - the browser adds the `Origin` request header (and makes a CORS preflight OPTIONS request if necessary) and checks for the various CORS response headers such as `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`.

Browsers only do this for fetch/XmlHTTPRequest (the latter is simply a wrapper for the former). So if you run your web service directly (outside of an actual browser), no CORS processing will occur on the client-side.

It's only when you run it within a browser that you'll see CORS issues.